Is $f(a) = EX^{1+a}EX^{-(1+a)}$ non-decreasing?
$X$ is a non-negative random variable and $a$ is a non-negative real number. Define
$$f(a)= EX^{1+a}EX^{-(1+a)}.$$
Is $f(a)$ non-decreasing with $a$?
Original problem: when I read a paper, I encounter an unproven inequality
$$\frac{\sum_{m=0}^{T-1}E_m^{1+\delta/2}\sum_{m=0}^{T-1}1/E_m^{1+\delta/2}}{T^2}\leq \frac{\sum_{m=0}^{T-1}E_m^{1+\delta_3}\sum_{m=0}^{T-1}1/E_m^{1+\delta_3}}{T^2}
$$
as a result of $\delta < \delta_3$. Here $E_m$'s are non-decreasing real numbers and $T$ is some positive integer. And I want to prove a stronger version of this result but I failed. I want to know if my conjecture is right? Or are there any counter-examples?

I guess that $E_m$ are non-negative real numbers instead of non-decreasing (the order of the $E_m$ does not matter).

Brackets are good.

Sorry @Yves. $E_m$ is non-negative (and is either non-decreasing or uniformly bounded).

Consider a uniform on $[1,2]$.
Then, for $a=0.1$ we get
$$
\int_{1}^2 x^{1+0.1} dx\cdot\int_{1}^2 \frac{1}{x^{1+0.1}} dx\approx1.2231
$$
but for $a=1$ we obtain
$$
\int_{1}^2 x^{1+1} dx\cdot\int_{1}^2 \frac{1}{x^{1+1}}dx\approx1.1667
$$
One could play around with the parameters in https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=%28int_1%5E2+x%5E%281%2B1%29+dx%29*%28int_1%5E2+1%2Fx%5E%281%2B1%29+dx%29 for illustration.

Thanks! But my quantity of interest is the product of $EX^{1+a}$ and $EX^{-(1+a)}$, NOT the ratio of them.

Sorry, made an edit
